# Nginx always redirect Laravel routes to default root index.php page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I'm a new Laravel learner. On my Mac (macOS 10.13), I have Nginx, PHP, and MySQL environment configured. At first, the Nginx localhost:8080/laravel/public displays the laravel welcome page without any issue. But when I try to add custom routes such as:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    return 'Hello World!';
});
```

I got 404 page on localhost:8080/laravel/public/test.

After I Googled the solution for route 404 issue, I modified my nginx conf file by adding

**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string**

as below:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now is the story, the 404 issue has be fixed. But I still cannot access the correct route page.

When I open localhost:8080/laravel/public/test again, **the browser takes me to the nginx docroot page (that is, localhost:8080/index.php).**

I have tried **php artisan serve** in my laravel home folder, using that command localhost:8000/test can be accessed correctly with "Hello World!" text.

Updated:

I just tried some other strings after localhost:8080/, such as localhost:8080/abc or something, it seems any subpath will takes me to the localhost:8080/index.php page! after **try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string** was added. If I remove this line of code, localhost:8080/abc will show 404 page (which should be correct because I don't have abc.php file in the root folder).

It seems like after adding

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Nginx redirects all the url it not recognized to the default homepage?

Can someone tell me why my Nginx cannot work with Laravel route after **try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string** is added?

If you need more detail, please let me know. Thanks very much!

Comment: Just for tip - Use Laravel Valet. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet
It'll helpful for lots of things while development.

Comment: What is your APP_URL value in .env?

Comment: @alariva APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: @imrealashu Thank you for your quick comment, I know there are a lot of easier ways to setup the dev environment, but just curious about why I encounters such issue. XD

Comment: @alariva I just changed the value to localhost:8080 but http://localhost:8080/laravel/public/test now displays "File not found."

Comment: What happens when you navigate `http://localhost:8080/laravel/test` ? Thats the URL you should visit if your `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080/laravel`, or visit `localhost:8080/test` if `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @alariva Hey alariva, I tried to change `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080/laravel` but `http://localhost:8080/laravel/test` still shows "File not found." `localhost:8080/test` shows the same error when APP_URL set to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Well.. I solved this issue by modifying my Nginx site config file, changing

```
server {

    ...

    root         /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

to

```
server {

    ...

    root         /var/www/laravel/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Yes, just **change the root path to laravel's public folder** then restart nginx server.

Now I got `Hello World!` on `http://localhost:8008/test`